# How do I handle result-based AsyncTasks without using activities?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Basically, I execute and AsyncTask to fetch me some details from my server. If the server replies that the user isn't logged in, I want to execute another AsyncTask to attempt to log in and then call my initial AsyncTask again.

I have a task X.
Based on the result of X(which i will get in X's onPostExecute(), I have to decide whether to call task Y.

Now, if Y's result is positive, I want to call X again.

Right now I'm using Activities for each AsyncTask so that I can handle the logic using the startActivityForResult and the onActivityResult functions. Is there anyway I can do the same thing using only AsyncTasks? Like call one AsyncTask from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have two different async tasks:

- one to compute the value of X;
- another to cover the negative result of X;

The described behavior can be easily implemented through [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s flow methods (onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute). Also, you can pass values between then using the argument/return mechams.

I see one of the async tasks like following:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, boolean, boolean> {
    @Override
    protected boolean doInBackground() {
        boolean result = [COMPUTE_X];
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean onProgressUpdate(boolean result) {
         return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
         if (!result) {
             new ComputeY_AsyncTask().execute();
         } else {
             // just go ahead
         }
    }
}
```

The another one is just like this, but must computate Y in background and call another instance of **MyAsyncTask** after Y's computation. In the end, all the proccesses gonna exit by [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) means. As stated by [[wtsang02]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336972/wtsang02), be careful to not put UI-updates inside doInBackground (do updates only in onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute) because it can even generate the **CalledFromWrongThread** exception!